# Raise PropertyChanged for a property inside a model

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm

So I've got a TimerModel which holds data for the entity and a TimerViewModel which handles the timer ticks from each one of the timers. It simply decrements the TimeSpan set as the interval for the timer - I'm doing this purely because I need to update the View with the remaining time.

```
public class TimerModel
{
    public TimerModel(TimeSpan Interval, TimerViewModel Parent)
    {
        Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        parent = Parent;

        this.Interval = Interval;

        Timer.Tick += (sender, args) => parent._timer_Tick(this, args);
        Timer.Start();
    }

    private TimerViewModel parent;

    public DispatcherTimer Timer
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public TimeSpan Interval
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And the TimerViewModel would be:

```
public class TimerViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public TimerViewModel()
    {
        Timers = new ObservableCollection<TimerModel>();
        AddTimerCommand = new RelayCommand((object x) => { AddTimer(x); });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TimerModel> Timers
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ICommand AddTimerCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private void AddTimer(object s)
    {
        Timers.Add(new TimerModel(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(250), this));
    }

    internal void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimerModel timer = sender as TimerModel;
        timer.Interval = timer.Interval.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        RaisePropertyChanged("Timers");
    }
}
```

Which is bound to a listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lst_timers" Height="300" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
DataContext="{Binding local:TimerViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Timers}" 
DisplayMemberPath="Interval" />
```

_timer_Tick should be raising the property changed for the whole list, but seemingly the listbox items remain unchanged. 
Can anyone give me a clue what am I missing here?

Comment: You are raising the event in _timer_tick event, but I don't see that you are changing the Timers. where are you calling AddTime from?,

Comment: I'm calling AddTimer from a command bound to a button control which is irrelevant to the current problem considering that it adds the timer successfully, but later on it is not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Timers` list is not changing, it's the `Interval` property of the `Timer` object that changes.

I'd suggest a ViewModel for your whole view (set as DataContext for your window/control..., not for the ListBox inside this parent window/control) containing a property `Timers` of type `ObervableCollection<TimerViewModel>`. This `TimerViewModel` represents one single timer and should raise a `PropertyChanged`-Event for `"Interval"` in the property's setter.

*(For additional information see comments)*

Comment: Exactly, but I have no idea how to achieve that, care to share an example?
EDIT: as far as I understand you I should be implementing INotifyPropertyChanged into a Model? Wouldn't that be against the guidelines of MVVM?

Comment: Your'e binding a model to the view (ItemsSoure=Timers). In my opinion, this is already against the guidelines of MVVM ;-) I think you need a ViewModel representing a single timer with the properties you need for your view (Interval...). This ViewModel is bound to the view and raises the needed event. PS: I can add an example later on if you need one...

Comment: Makes sense, but how would I bind otherwise? I'm still struggling to get a proper grasp of the MVVM, so any piece of advice is welcome!
Am I supposed to make a viewmodel that holds an ObservableCollection of viewmodels?

Comment: Yes I'd suggest a ViewModel for your whole view (set as `DataContext` for your window/control..., not for the ListBox inside this parent window/control) containing a property `Timers` of type `ObervableCollection<TimerViewModel>`. This TimerViewModel represents one single timer.

Comment: Makes sense, and opens a whole new bunch of possibilities! I thought I wasn't meant to do that. Gonna check it out in just a while as I rewrite it and mark this as an answer - also you might wanna edit it and point out that your answer is in the comments.

Comment: I've managed to do it without adding additional VMs (eg. TimerListViewModel). I figured that a model should be having a INotifyPropertyChanged as well - according to a mvvm simplified article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MVVMForDummies.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
<ListBox x:Name="lst_timers" ...>
    <ListBox.DataContext>
      <local:TimerViewModel/> 
    </ListBox.DataContext>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Did that already... `DataContext="{Binding local:TimerViewModel}`

Comment: That part worked perfectly properly, refer to Stephan's answer for a clue on what issues I've had.

Comment: Andy, I owe you an apology, I've just come to conclusion that I have done the bindings in the code behind file, so I could have done the bindings improperly, but I would appreciate if you'd elaborate or point me out to an article that could explain me why is my way of doing it wrong.